# How to add keyboard function to label tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've finished a basic calculator in tkinter python, and all that's left to do now is allow the user to use the keyboard in the calculator as well.
I've tried using the config function but that ends up just replacing all of the text in the label, as usual.
This is the code for the calculator so far.

```
from tkinter import *
e = Tk(className="Krishna's Calculator")
e.geometry("460x614")
e.resizable(bool(0),bool(0))
def insert(value):
    var.set(var.get() + value)
    eval(var.get())
def button(text, width, font, highlightbackground, x, y):
    tkinter_button = Button(e, text=text, width=width, command=lambda: insert(text), font=font, highlightbackground=highlightbackground)
    tkinter_button.place(x=x, y=y)
def clear():
    var.set(" ") 
def equals(vare):
    var.set(eval(vare))
helvetica = "Helvetica 50"   
arial = "Arial 50 bold"
var = StringVar()
label = Label(e, textvariable = var,bd=5,width=16, relief = SOLID, font = "Arial 50 ",bg="white", fg="black",activebackground="#bb99ff", height = 5,pady = 3)
label.place(x=0,y=0)
button(text = "-", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 426)
button(text = "+", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 488)
equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=4, command = lambda: equals(var.get()), font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#8533ff')
equal.place(x = 344, y = 551)
aclear = Button(e, text = "AC",width=4, command = clear, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
aclear.place(x = 0, y = 302)
square = Button(e, text = "^",width=4, command = lambda: insert("**"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
square.place(x = 228, y = 301)
divide = Button(e, text = "÷",width=4, command = lambda: insert("/"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#8533ff')
divide.place(x = 344, y = 301)
multiply = Button(e, text = "x",width=4, command = lambda: insert("*"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#8533ff')
multiply.place(x = 344, y = 364)
delete = Button(e, text = "C",width=4, command=lambda: var.set(var.get()[:-1]), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
delete.place(x = 114, y = 302)
button(text = ".", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 550)
button(text = "0", width = 8, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 550)
button(text = "1", width =4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 488)
button(text = "2", width =4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 488)
button(text = "3", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 488)
button(text = "4", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 426)
button(text = "5", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 426)
button(text = "6", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 426)
button(text = "7", width=4, font = arial ,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 364)
button(text = "8", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 364)
button(text = "9", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 364)
e.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`the_widget.bind('<Key>', lambda event: the_function())`
see this website:https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-key-binding/

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using the config function but that ends up just replacing
> all of the text in the label, as usual. This is the code for the
> calculator so far.

**Your code is working**.

- In `insert` function in line 7, Add trap `try/execpt` to prevent
  multiplication.
- Use same `font="Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#737373'` for all
  widgets. You can suit your need.
- change all location `Button` widgets for `x` and `y`
- Change wide to 3.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

e = Tk(className="Krishna's Calculator")
e.geometry("518x980")
#e.resizable(bool(0),bool(0))

def insert(value):
    try:
        var.set(var.get() + value)
        eval(var.get())
    except:
        pass
    
def button(text, width, font, highlightbackground, x, y):
    tkinter_button = Button(e, text=text, width=width, command=lambda: insert(text), font=font, highlightbackground=highlightbackground)
    tkinter_button.place(x=x, y=y)
    
def clear():
    var.set(" ")
    
def equals(vare):
    var.set(eval(vare))
    
helvetica = "Helvetica 50"   
arial = "Arial 50 bold"

var = StringVar()

label = Label(e, textvariable = var,bd=5,width=13, relief = SOLID, font = "Arial 50 ",bg="white", fg="black",activebackground="#bb99ff", height = 5,pady = 3)
label.place(x=0,y=0)

button(text = "-", width=3, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#737373', x = 377, y = 392)
button(text = "+", width=3, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#737373', x = 377, y = 733)

equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=3, command = lambda: equals(var.get()), font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#8533ff')
equal.place(x = 377, y = 863)

aclear = Button(e, text = "AC",width=3, command = clear, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
aclear.place(x = 0, y = 392)

square = Button(e, text = "^",width=3, command = lambda: insert("**"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
square.place(x = 252, y = 392)

divide = Button(e, text = "÷",width=3, command = lambda: insert("/"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
divide.place(x = 377, y = 624)

multiply = Button(e, text = "x",width=3, command = lambda: insert("*"), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
multiply.place(x = 377, y = 523)

delete = Button(e, text = "C",width=3, command=lambda: var.set(var.get()[:-1]), font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
delete.place(x = 127, y = 392)

button(text = ".", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 253, y = 863)
button(text = "0", width =6, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373',x = 0, y = 842)
button(text = "1", width =3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 0, y = 733)
button(text = "2", width =3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 127, y = 733)
button(text = "3", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 253, y = 733)
button(text = "4", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 0, y = 624)
button(text = "5", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 127, y = 624)
button(text = "6", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373', x = 253, y = 624)
button(text = "7", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#737373', x = 0, y = 523)
button(text = "8", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#737373', x = 127, y = 523)
button(text = "9", width=3, font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#737373', x = 254, y = 523)
e.mainloop()
```

Screenshot: See all mode buttons.

[image]